# Adding items to observable collection causing exception with collection view

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

So I have an `ObservableCollection<Foo>` and I add an item to it like this:

```
Items.AddFromThread(svm);
```

Where `AddFromThread` is an extension method that looks like this:

```
public static void AddFromThread<T>(this ICollection<T> s, T obj)
{
    if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread != System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => s.AddFromThread(obj)), null);
    }
    else
    {
        s.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

This was working fine, but just recently I've started getting errors with the `Add` method:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

Now I'm adding my item to my `ObservableCollection` *from the dispatcher thread* - that's what the check is for, so this seems like it should be impossible. But it's complaining not about my observable collection, but about the `CollectionView`. My UI is actually binding an `ICollectionView` that is created from `Items` like this:

```
filteredItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
```

So what is happening here? If I'm adding from the UI thread, shouldn't the `CollectionView` be getting updated from the same thread? If not, how do I make it so that it does.

The worse part is that this was working fine for a long time and I didn't change anything that might have impacted this as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

Ok - so a little investigation and it appears that the `CollectionView` was being created on a different thread itself and that seems to be the root of the problem. Although why it didn't seem to be a problem before is still puzzling.

So I fixed it to make sure that the code that creates the `CollectionView` is also running on the `Dispatcher.Thread`. The error message was misleading in this case. The problem wasn't that I was trying to add from a non-UI thread, the problem was that *I was adding from a UI thread*, but to something that lived on a different thread.